My character does not do what I expected him to do and I dont know why
I am making a 2d game in unity and I haven't touched a game engine in months but I found this movement script I had saved which I wrote a while ago, I set everything up and when I was going to try, my wall jump was off. Instead of just going up diagonaly up and sideways like every wall jump mine simply goes to the side at a very not intended fast speed. I really can't recall if this script was working back then but I dont think I would save something that doesnt work
    private Vector2 wallJumpingPower = new Vector2(10f, 20f);
    private float wallJumpDirection;

   
    if (IsWalled()) //the isWalled() method is working
    {   
        wallJumpDirection = -transform.localScale.x;
        WallJump();
        wallSlide();
    }

    private void WallJump()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(wallJumpingPower.x * wallJumpDirection, wallJumpingPower.y);
        }
    }

    private void wallSlide()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -0.4f); //this is the wall slide and it works
        if (hasDoubleJumped)
        {
            canDoubleJump = true; //this is irrelevant
        }
    }


In the WallJump function you set the object's x velocity as wallJumpingPower.x * wallJumpDirection. You previously had set the wallJumpingPower.x equal to 10 and wallJumpDirection equal to -transform.localScale.x. So when you do set the object's x velocity to be wallJumpingPower.x * wallJumpDirection, you are setting its x velocity to be 10 * -transform.localScale.x which is likely going to be a very fast speed because even if -transform.localScale.x = -1 the x component of the velocity would be -10 which is quite fast. The value you set the y component of the velocity inside the WallJump does not matter because you override that value in the wallSlide function where you set the y component of the velocity to -0.4 which is a small value compared to the 10 * -transform.localScale.x which the x component is being set to making the object look like it is moving horizontal.
If you want the wall jump function to move the object diagonally you need the decrease the x and y components of wallJumpingPower to slow it down and not call the wallSlide function if Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") == true to avoid overriding the y component of the object's velocity.
